# cpu time in docplex

Tags: modeling, python, cplex, docplex, cpu

```
mdl.print_information()
sol = mdl.solve()
mdl.print_solution()     


if sol is None:
    print("Infeasible")
    
print(mdl.solve_details)
```

At the end of the mathematical model in docplex I have the code above and **solve time** is printed in the console. But I am not sure about if it is **CPU time** or not.
How can I print the CPU time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , that's CPU time.
If you want real time then use the python time module

Comment: Can I write the CPU time to excel as a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, you can get the value with mdl.solve_details.timeas you can see at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoogetcplexinfo.py and then build a dataframe